# Why passing a React state array to component make it array of one array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have const

```
  const [filesData, setFilesData] = React.useState<IFileData[]>([]);
```

Then a call to a child component

```
{filesData.length > 0 && <FilesDataList  filesData = {filesData} setFilesData = {setFilesData}  /> }
```

Then in the Component "FilesDataList"

```
export const FilesDataList = (props) => {
```

I find that the array "props" is props.filesData is not the actual filesData array but an array that contains one item that is the actual filesData array

```
props.filesData  [Array(1)]
0: Array(1)
0: {Id: "Test0.docx", Instructions: "for Test0.docx", SelectService: "new", PageRange: "new", Hours: 0}
length: 1
```

So to use the array I need to use

```
 props.filesData[0]
```

Can any one explain it and maybe give me a better way to do it?

Comment: Can we see how you are calling `setFilesData`?

Comment: It looks like `props.filesData[0]` is an object not an array.  Is filesData supposed to be an object?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling `setFilesData` by pushing an array with your data into the `filesData` array that already exists.

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
let filesData = [1,2,3];
let newData = [4];
filesData.push(newData);

console.log(filesData); //[ 1, 2, 3, [ 4 ] ]

setFilesData(filesData); // sets it as an array within an array
```

Instead, we want to create a new array with the contents of `newData`.

```
setFilesData([...filesData, ...newData]);
```

That spreads everything already in `filesData`, and adds the content of `newData` which is the next object you want to add.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Turned out I use a map of another array and that pushed an array. When I change it to push in a .forEach, it made me a clean new array of object items. Thanks and sorry for the bother :-)

Comment: Glad you found the bug!